# How to access template block from plugin within Django CMS Placeholder

Tags: django, django-cms

I have the following code:

**base.html**

```
<html>
...
{% block test_block %}
    {# Some stuff to render #}
{% endblock %}
...
</html>
```

**main_template.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}    
...
{% block content %}
    {% placeholder "content" %}
{% endblock %}
...
```

**plugin.html**

```
...
```

If I add my plugin to the page it renders in the placeholder block, as expected.

If I amend plugin.html to add the following:

**plugin.html**

```
...
{% block test_block %}
    {{ block.super }}
    {# Some more stuff to render #}
{% endblock %}
...
```

Then I receive an error:
'BlockNode' object has no attribute 'context'. Did you use {{ block.super }} in a base template?

If I try and extend either main_template.html or CMS_TEMPLATE (they seem to be the same?) from within **plugin.html** I get the following error:
maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

How can I access and append to test_block from within my plugin?

Comment: What does plugin extend from?

Comment: As far as I can tell, nothing. There's no {% extends %} tag at the top of plugin.html but adding one results in the max recursion depth error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use a block you must, I believe, do so in a template which extends from a template where that block is defined.

However, to do what you want, CMS makes use of [`django-sekizai`](https://django-sekizai.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

With this you can have this in `base.html`;

```
{% load sekizai_tags %}
<html>
    ...
    {% render_block "test_block" %}
    ...
</html>
```

And then in `plugin.html` you can do;

```
{% load sekizai_tags %}
{% addtoblock "test_block" %}
    Add this to my block
{% endaddtoblock %}
```

This is often used for CSS & JS blocks, but works perfectly well for what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you Mark, I'll try this out. I guess what I wasn't sure about was whether plugins that are rendered within a placeholder implicitly extend their parent (main_template.html, in my case). I will give it a try using django-sekizai and get back to you in a few days.

Comment: Well your plugin could get used on any page, and you might have various page templates for different types of pages. Sekizai is great though for getting JS or CSS included in the `base.html` that is specific to the plugin, so it should do what you want.

Comment: @AndyF how did you get on with this?

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for getting back to me. Sorry for the delay. Django Sekizai worked like a charm.